# Spring Integration - Grouping Adapter & Fault Isoloation

Tags: spring-integration

I`m trying to configure Spring Integration for Interfacing my applications. The flow like below.

Some Http Request Client
-> Spring Integration(What I Working at)
-> Some Http Response Servers

```
//Create Channel
DirectChannel directChannel = new DirectChannel();
directChannel.setComponentName("SampleChannel");
directChannel.setFailover(false);

//Create Inbound
IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("/foo")).channel("SampleChannel").get();

//Create Outbound
IntegrationFlows.from("SampleChannel").handle(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler).get();
IntegrationFlows.from("SampleChannel").handle(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler).get();
IntegrationFlows.from("SampleChannel").handle(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler).get();

//Some Codes for dynamic bean regist
...
```

is there any way not to request to outbound server that something wrong(Http Server is down or Connection Refuse, not 4XX/5XX error)?

Comment: "is there any way not to request to outbound server that something wrong" - uh, that is not a sentence. Please clarify what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to have a Circuit Breaker on your HTTP outbound gateway : https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#circuit-breaker-advice. And probably Retry Advice : https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#retry-advice. Otherwise really, please, rephrase your question...